# React-native-jitsi-meet no button is working

Tags: android, react-native, jitsi-meet

In react-native-jitsi-meet i am getting following errors

```
E/JitsiMeetSDK: [features/app] Error(TypeError)
{"message":"l.playTouchSound is not a function. (In 
'l.playTouchSound()', 'l.playTouchSound' is 
undefined)",
"stack":"_playTouchSound@index.android.bundle:209:9252\n_playTouchSound@[native 
code]\n_performSideEffectsForTransition@index.android.bundle:209:9074
\n_performSideEffectsForTransition@[native 
code]\n_receiveSignal@index.android.bundle:209:7784\n_receiveSignal@[native 
code]\ntouchableHandleResponderRelease@index.android.bundle:209:5072\n
touchableHandleResponderRelease@[native 
code]\nb@index.android.bundle:92:1197\nk@index.android.bundle:92:1340
\nC@index.android.bundle:92:1394\nN@index.android.bundle:92:1692\nA@index.android.bundle:92:2482\nforEach@[native 
code]\nz@index.android.bundle:92:2282\nindex.android.bundle:92:13914\n_e@index.android.bundle:92:88659\nNe@index.android.bundle:92:13582\n
Ue@index.android.bundle:92:13755\nreceiveTouches@index.android.bundle
:92:14547\nvalue@index.android.bundle:37:3676\nindex.android.bundle:3
7:832\nvalue@index.android.bundle:37:2930\nvalue@index.android.bundle
:37:804\nvalue@[native code]"}
```

when i click on any of the button

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: did anyone find the solution? facing this same issue